# Scanner.nextLine() ignores whitespace? (Java)

Tags: java, junit, command-line-interface, java.util.scanner

I have a command-line game and am testing with JUnit, this is the test:

```
@Test
  public void testBattle() throws IOException{
    String input = "go forward\ngo left\ntake Pointy Stick\ngo backward\ngo " +
            "right\nnormal attack\nnormal attack\nquit\n";
    provideInput(input);
    actual = new File("src/main/testFiles/testBattle.txt");
    expected = new File("src/main/testFiles/testBattleExpected.txt");
    PrintStream o = new PrintStream(actual);
    System.setOut(o);

    ui.gameLoop();
    assertTrue(FileUtils.contentEqualsIgnoreEOL(actual, expected, null));

  }
```

And this is the provide input method:

```
 private void provideInput(String data) {
    String newdata = data.trim();
    testIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(newdata.getBytes());
    System.setIn(testIn);
  }
```

I'm doing scanner nextline so:

```
command = input.nextLine().toLowerCase().trim();
```

where "input" here represents the scanner object
but I'm still getting this error, specifically when the first "normal attack" is passed into System.in

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
```

on that line above. I thought nextline ignored whitespace? If not did I format my string wrong to not include it?

EDIT:
From the first few lines of UI.gameLoop() I only initialize the scanner once.

```
public void gameLoop() throws IOException, JsonSyntaxException {
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    engine = new GameEngine(path);
```

Comment: You thought nextline ignored whitespace why? Have you considered consulting the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

> I thought nextline ignored whitespace?

Nope.  According to the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()), it reads past the next end-of-line sequence (or to EOF), and then returns everything up to but not including the end-of-line sequence.

If you are getting

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
```

that means that the `Scanner` has *already* reached the end of the input stream, or (maybe) the `Scanner` is trying to read from an input stream that was prematurely closed somewhere else in your code.

We can make guesses about what the real problem is, but without seeing >>your<< [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), we can't take this much further.

---

Actually, I just spotted a clue:

> ... I am testing with JUnit ...

This is possibly at the root of your problems.  A JVM can only "read to the end of `System.in`" once in its lifetime.  If you have two or more JUnit tests that need to do this, it is going to be difficult, unless you can find a way to "mock" the `System.in` variable.

It may be simpler to reorganize your code so that you take the input from some stream that is passed to your game code as a parameter.  By reorganizing you can make it easier to write unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot to go on, but I'm guessing you're creating multiple Scanners, one for each time you want to read a line. This usually works ok interactively since humans are slow typers, but fails when each Scanner's readahead ends up consuming multiple lines.

You can see the difference in this MCVE:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Foo {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String newdata = "go forward\ngo left\ntake Pointy Stick\ngo backward\ngo " +
                  "right\nnormal attack\nnormal attack\nquit\n".trim();
    ByteArrayInputStream testIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(newdata.getBytes());
    System.setIn(testIn);

    boolean includeBug = Boolean.valueOf(args[0]);

    if (includeBug) {

      for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Read: " + input.nextLine());
      }

    } else {

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
        System.out.println("Read: " + input.nextLine());
      }

    }
  }
}
```

When `includeBug` is true, it creates a new Scanner for each line and crashes like you say. If it's false, it creates a single Scanner and works correctly:

```
$ javac Foo.java
$ java Foo true
Read: go forward
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
        at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
        at Foo.main(Foo.java:17)

$ java Foo false
Read: go forward
Read: go left
Read: take Pointy Stick
Read: go backward
(etc)
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the comment I tried looking for any initialization for new scanners but could only find that my scanner is initialized once at the beginning of game loop (check my edit for details). I do however pass the scanner into the constructor of another object, would this duplicate the scanner?

Comment: Passing the Scanner somewhere won't duplicate it, no. The problem description does still suggest competing readers though.

Comment: Oh wait I just realized that the problem was that I was messing with my scanner instantation. Because I passed it into a constructor I didn't realize that the class was using the scanner at the same time as my UI!

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking if it has a next line? With Scanners, you usually either have to handle the exception (not really something I'd prefer) or you have to use the [hasNextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine%28%29) method to avoid the exception.

```
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
     command = input.nextLine().toLowerCase().trim();
}
```